# Samba 'smb passwd file' setting doesnt work

Tags: debian, samba, debian-squeeze

after upgrading debian from lenny to squeeze (and samba to 3.5.6 version) all user account seems to be deleted. I have to recreate them using `smbpasswd -a username` and then set new password.

Second thing is that I've `smb passwd file = /etc/samba/passwd` option set in config file but it doesnt work in new version of samba. I really dont know where the passwords are stored now.
How to restore all previous samba user accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samba uses TDB format databases as a faster alternative to textual `smbpasswd` files. The account database is located at `/var/lib/samba/passdb.tdb` by default. Use `pdbedit --import`.

Comment: So the "smb passwd file" option is ignored?

Comment: @daftu: See "`passdb backend`" in the manual of `smb.conf`.